# Does DocumentDB provide auto indexing or not?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

The documentation for documentDB suggest that it provides automatic indexing here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing/

But the sample code for it (on azure portal) shows manual index policy creation as shown below:

```
DocumentCollection collectionInfo = new DocumentCollection();
collectionInfo.Id = collectionName;
// Configure collections for maximum query flexibility including string range queries.
collectionInfo.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) {
    Precision = -1
});
```

If documentDB provides automatic indexing, then why do I need to create the index policy manually again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default 3-byte hash index on every field. You can override the indexing policy for specific fields/types using the indexing policy settings. If you want range indexes or you want to change the precision of the index, you do that with a policy. You need to set a range index on any field where you want to use `ORDER BY` among other common uses. So, yes, both statements are true. It provides automatic indexing but you can also specify the indexing.

Comment: Does auto indexing include range indexing on strings? If yes, then I don't need to manually set string range index policy. Please confirm.

Comment: No, it does not. It will only do a hash index on strings or numbers. You will need to manually set an indexing policy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DocumentDB provides schema agnostic, automatic indexing - implying all paths for every document are consistently indexed, across any kind of schema changes among the documents.

Note that the default policy is set to index numbers with full fidelity range support, while strings are indexed with a hash function. These defaults are chosen to give a compelling query performance with minimal storage overhead.

The indexing policy is available for users to override the default behaviors for the following cases -

1. Opt out any specific path from indexing, as part of Excluded paths. This helps in reducing the RU charge incurred in the write path and depending on the number of paths excluded, this can lead to storage gains as well.
2. Tweak the index kind (hash/range/spatial) and precision of indexing (higher precision implies better query performance with a slightly increased storage cost) on a selected included indexing path.

Full details of the indexing policy are here

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/